# .NET application using third-party library (with reflection) older .NET version

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Third party library (Helper.dll) from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49003/SCSI-Library-in-C-Burn-CDs-and-DVDs-Access-Hard-Di use .NET 2.0. Main application use .NET 4.5.
There is following code in library:

```
memcpyimpl = (memcpyimplDelegate) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(memcpyimplDelegate), typeof(Buffer).GetMethod("memcpyimpl", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static));
```

where

```
public unsafe delegate void memcpyimplDelegate(byte* src, byte* dest, int len);
```

in runtime raise error, because, probably, this code using Buffer class from latest assembly, but there is no Buffer.memcpyimpl method in .NET 4.5.

How to make library to use Buffer class from .NET 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library will use .NET version of your app. See [Version Compatibility in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx) on MSDN.

If you have control over the component, just fix it. Never ever rely on private members, reimplement them instead.

If you have no control over the component and can't switch to .NET 2.0, your only option is moving the component into a separate process.

Answer (score 5):

Using Reflection to call a private method of a class is indeed a good way to get code to fail on a different version of .NET.  The Buffer class has changed in .NET 4.x, the method is now named `_Memcpy`.

You can get a more resilient version of the method by ab/using a DLL that's present on every version of Windows and will already be loaded into your process since Windows itself uses it.  Not completely safe either, Microsoft might change the DLL some day.  But very unlikely, there's lots of open source tooling that uses it (MinGW for example).

```
  [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
  private static unsafe extern int memcpy(byte* dest, byte* srce, int bytes);
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks out lot! I think I found "true" sources of used library and change field inicialization to

```
public static readonly unsafe memcpyimplDelegate memcpyimpl =
    (memcpyimplDelegate)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
        typeof(memcpyimplDelegate),
        typeof(Buffer).GetMethod("memcpyimpl",
            BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
     ?? typeof(Buffer).GetMethod("Memcpy",
            BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
            null, new Type[] { typeof(byte*), typeof(byte*), typeof(int) }, null)
     );
```

Not very good at all (in fact very bad), but it will works in .NET 4.0 and 4.5 and maybe next several years.